# How to open rails console for access multiple database in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

i have multiple databases in my project and i want to open rails console to access both databases.

currently i can fetch data of only one default database.

In other word, how to open specific database console?

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried? What is the error? What are the databases? How are they configured? How is activerecord setup? Generally a rails console will have connections to all databases and activerecord will connect to the one they're configured to... so you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

> In other word, how to open specific database console?

From [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-dbconsole):

> `bin/rails dbconsole` figures out which database you're using and drops you into whichever command line interface you would use with it (and figures out the command line parameters to give to it, too!). It supports MySQL (including MariaDB), PostgreSQL, and SQLite3.
>
> You can also use the alias "db" to invoke the dbconsole: `bin/rails db`.
>
> If you are using multiple databases, `bin/rails dbconsole` will
> connect to the primary database by default. You can specify which
> database to connect to using `--database` or `--db`:
>
> ```
> bin/rails dbconsole --database=animals
> ```

So command is

```
rails db --db=db_name_from_database_yml
```

For example you have in your `database.yml`

```
production:
  my_primary:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: some_db_name
```

In this case your command will be

```
bundle exec rails db --db=my_primary -e=production
```

Comment: @machnicov This is not the correct answer. I want to open rails console not db console.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JigarBhatt it means your question is not correct, not my answer. Please read it again and edit question if necessary

Comment: yes i updated my question, now do you know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have a read through the documentation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html.
You should be able to find just what you need. connects_to does the trick of database switching automatically of manually.

Or
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-connected_to

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :mydb) do
  # Do something here...
end
```